# INSERT INTO sql sentence is not working"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm making a sign up page 
**whats wrong with my code ?
when i view the program in browser it says:**
(Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.)

```
public partial class Sign_Up2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPass.Text != "" &&
            txtUname.Text != "" &&
            txtRePass.Text != "")
        {
            if (txtPass.Text.ToString().Trim() == txtRePass.Text.ToString().Trim())
            {
                string str ="INSERT INTO T1 (Username,Password) VALUES('" + txtUname.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtPass.Text.ToString() + "');";
                DAL.ChangeTable(str);
                Response.Redirect("log in.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when the username or password contain a `'` character? (Hint: you have a security vulnerability.)

Comment: Yep - an apostrophe (or a semicolon) could cause you grief when embedded within the variables.  You should be using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

remove semicolon from the query

```
"INSERT INTO T1 (Username,Password) VALUES('" + txtUname.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtPass.Text.ToString() + "');";
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO T1 (Username,Password) VALUES('" + txtUname.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtPass.Text.ToString() + "')";
```

Comment: check last semicolun after closing braces